# Recursively scan a Windows FTP server using PHP hangs midway... why?

Tags: php, recursion, ftp

I needed to map a FTP server (running on Windows) using PHP, so I made a function that essentially navigates through the FTP's folder structure, listing everything inside it and calls itself recursively when it encounters a subfolder.

Everything worked fine in my development environment, but things took a sour turn once I migrated everything to the client's infrastructure. Their FTP server holds 30GB of data (a lot of files, but not as many as you would expect, since many are > 100MB), so I was expecting it to be "slowish", but 90 to 120 seconds seemed a lot.

Therefore, I did some investigating with tcpdump and it is perfectly visible that the FTP server has some kind of **anti-flood protection** because at a given point every request gets stalled for at least 60 seconds. This behavior **also happens** if I attempt to map the server recursively **using lftp**.

I am currently using active mode because passive threw the following error:

```
Warning: ftp_rawlist() [function.ftp-rawlist]: php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /home/user/public_html/sync.php on line 35
```

Line 35 refers to a ftp_rawlist of the current directory.

I not really sure it'll help, but here's the code I'm using anyway:

```
function ftp_get_recursive_paths($conn, $path, $root, $max_level = 0) {
    $files = array();
    $contents = ftp_rawlist($conn, $path);

    if(is_array($contents)) {
        foreach($contents as $line) {
            (...) Parsing the results (...)
            if ((strpos($f, ".DS_Store") === false) && (strpos($f, ".dropbox") === false) && (strpos($f, "Thumbs.db") === false)) {

                if(!strpos($f, '.')) {
                    $init = microtime(true);
                    $files[$f] = (object) array('name' => $f, 'date' => $date, 'path' => $path . $f, 'content' => ftp_get_recursive_paths($conn, $path . $f, $path));
                    $end = microtime(true);
                    echo '<p> Folder ' . $path . $f . ' scanned in '. ($end - $init), ' seconds. </p>';
                }
                else {
                    $files[] = (object) array('name' => $f, 'date' => $date, 'path' => $path .  $f);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Does anyone know how this anti-flood thing can be prevented? Is it a firewall? Some kind of configuration in the client's server?

I can confirm that the client is using Filezilla Server on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the client did have a firewall of some sort that blocked the requests after a certain threshold.

TL;DR: everybody lies.

Answer (score 0):

also when using locally (connect to ftp where the on the same server with the .php) if you use "sftp" it will work, but remotely you have to use "ftp" or configure well the remote client